# How to install tmux inside a dev container established through the "dev environment" option on docker for a local repository?

Tags: docker, tmux

I've cloned a github repo and ran into roadblocks trying to set it up locally so used Docker's dev environment option on it. The repo needs tmux as part of the build process and I can't install it inside the Docker environment cause it's linked to the repo and there's no mention of it there

Tried `brew install` and then realised I'm inside a container...

Comment: It depends on the operating system of the container. If it's ubuntu, for instance, you can use `apt-get` to install `tmux`. Other platforms will have other package managers.

Comment: `tmux` seems like an odd build-time dependency for anything except maybe `tmux` plugins.

Comment: @AlexGrounds yep. Can just install it straight through the CLI

Answer (score 0):

You can just install it. I started docker a few hours back so I was confused.
Since its a Linux based image just run `sudo apt-get update`, then `apt-get -y install curl` and `sudo apt-get  install tmux` in the docker cli